# Unable to connect mysql with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, mysql-connector

Hlo everyone. I want help in connecting mysql with Visual Studio Code. OS- Window

Oracle MySql is already installed in my pc and I want to connect it to VSCode. For that I have also installed MySql Management tool in VSCode.

The problem is that VSCode couldn't find mysql driver.

I have tried my best and checked online solution (Google and YouTube) but all in vain.

I can share my screen so that you can check what's the problem.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting ? Is it ClassNotFoundException or something else?

Comment: The answer also depends on the programming language  and operating system used, which you have not indicated. VS Code is a dev environment that supports a variety of programming languages and operating systems.

Comment: @makarand when I am clicking on 'Add Connection' it's showing that no database driver found.

Comment: @Shadow OS-Windows. When we open VScode it shows a database icon on LHS, by clicking which it shows list of database installed. And it's not compulsory to write a program to connect MySql to VSCode, we can directly connect it first.

Comment: @Nik check for the jdbc driver for mysql once, that might be the problem. After checking that specify the classpath of your jdbc driver into environment variables. e,g edit environment variables-> user variables-> classpath ->new -> C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.49\mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar , append this to your classpath and restart the VSCode , hope it helps

Comment: @makarand look jdbc  programs are working fine and running properly. The only problem is that when I am trying to connect MySql to VScode it's showing that couldn't find any database drivers. Hey, can I send a google meet link to you, so that I can share my pc screen and you can understand what's the problem.

Comment: Actually I am quite busy these days [this](https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/590) might help

Comment: Ok thnaks for your help @makarand